# Add an empty object in a request payload in Karate testcase

Tags: java, cucumber, karate

How to insert a empty object in the request payload in karate . Need to send an empty emp object in the payload

Sample Payload

```
{"empInfo":{}}
```

Tried the syntax below, did not work.

- set aReq.acctInfo == {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked

- set payload.empInfo = {};